# How to do long-polling on tornado server while simultaneously sending data to server?

Tags: javascript, python, async-await, tornado, long-polling

#### Goal

I want to implement a dashboard (webpage) which allows to authorize connected clients to interact with a server (server running Tornado, Python). The currently authorized clients are stored in a "client-array" on the server. The dashboard is long-polling for updates, so it shows changes in the array as soon as they happen.
As the clients can be authorized via button-press in the dashboard, an authorize-request has to be sent to the server simultaneously to the long-polling.

Btw: I am aware, that for this particular use case, long-polling is not necessary. But there are other cases later in the project which require long polling, so I try to make it work for this case, too.

#### Current behaviour and Problem

Once the dashboard (and the currently connected clients) were loaded, the dashboard starts long-polling for updates. The server is aware of this connection and waits for changes to happen.
When authorizing a client via button-press, the server receives the authorize-request and changes the client-array respectively. These changes cause the server to send updated HTML to the dashboard. After that, it sends another answer to the authorize-request.

But the updated HTML sent by the server is not received by the dashboard. As if it was never sent or the dashboard somehow does not wait for it anymore.
The answer to the authorize-request, triggered by the button, is received, though.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

***Pay attention to the edits below***

#### Code

The dashboard's code (JavaScript):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    requestClientUpdates();
};

async function requestClientUpdates() {
    let response = await fetch(window.location.pathname, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: "req-type=update"  // request for getting updates
    });

    if (response.status === 502) {
        console.log("502: " + response.statusText);
    } else if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    } else {
        updateDashboardHTML(response.text());   // dummy function
        // this doesn't ever get called
    }

    requestClientUpdates();  // immediately poll for updates again
}

// triggered on button-press
function authorizeClient() {
    var data = "req-type=authorize-client";   // along with some more data
    let response = fetch(window.location.pathname, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: data
    });

    if (response.status === 502) {
        console.log("502: " + response.statusText);
    } else if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    } else {
        console.log("authorized");
        // gets called
    }
}
```

The server's handler for long-polling- and command-requests (Python with Tornado-Framework):

```
class ClientManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.condition = tornado.locks.Condition()
        self.authorized_clients = []

    def authorize_client(self, id):
        """Adds client with given ID to connected clients"""
        client = get_client(id)  # returns client object with more data
        self.authorized_clients.append(client)
        self.announce_update()

    def announce_update(self):
        self.condition.notify()


client_manager = ClientManager()


class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def send_current_client_overview(self):
        data = generatingHTMLforDashboard()  # dummy for the actual code
        self.write(data)  # is reached properly (as tests have shown)

    async def post(self):
        req_type = self.get_arguments("req-type")
        if "authorize-client" in req_type:
            client_manager.authorize_client(self.get_argument("id"))
        elif "update" in req_type:
            await client_manager.condition.wait()
            self.send_current_client_overview()

def main():
    app.listen(port)  # server application was prepared before
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

#### Edit

[See comment below] The response is received, but only in specific situations. After the server was freshly restarted and the dashboard was freshly entered (not just a refresh. The JavaScript must not have run before). Once the dashboard is refreshed, it doesn't work anymore and the server has to be restarted etc.

#### Edit 2

Made multiple changes:

**#1**: await response.text(), even if you await response already. Otherwise the promise "response" might not be fulfilled yet.

```js
async function requestClientUpdates() {
    let response = await fetch(window.location.pathname, {
        // pack request
    });

    // catch errors
    else {
        var answer = await response.text();  // make sure it is fulfilled before usage
        // continue working with answer
    }

    requestClientUpdates();  // immediately poll for updates again
}
```

**#2** *(this caused the problem)*: cancel futures, once a connection closes. Therefore, overwrite the Handler's on_connection_close():

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.wait_future = None

    async def post(self):
        if "update" in req_type:
            # save Future returned here so it can be canceled on on_connection_close()
            self.wait_future = client_manager.condition.wait()
            try:
                await self.wait_future
            # catch exception in case future was cancelled due to a closed connection
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                return
            self.send_current_client_overview()

    def on_connection_close(self):
        if self.wait_future is not None:
            self.wait_future.cancel()
```

These changes still leave the code with a `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` printed in Forefox' console once refreshing the page, but apart from that the dashboard behaves as expected.

Comment: `this doesn't ever get called` so, you never get 200 status response? If not, the problem is on the server side. What response status DO you get? If you do get a 200 response, then the problem may be what you do with the promise passed to `updateDashboardHTML`

Comment: @JaromandaX I got no response...I thought. I've tested a bit more: I have to restart the server. And reenter the dashboard (not just refresh the page). Then it works like a charm, I can authorize clients and it updates. But as soon as I reload the page or reenter it while the server was previously serving it once, the console shows `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` and he described behaviour appears. Have to restart server and reenter page again to make it work

Comment: `NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` - so, server error? any logs or anything you can check on the server

Comment: I was taking a closer look to the debugging options, logging options and own prints. Turns out I had multiple requests going on at the same time. Fixed that, wasn't the solution for the error, though. But at some point I remembered a line from the tornado doc (see my edit). Doesn't fix `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` but the actual problem described in the beginning